# "for" loop from program 7.6 from Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C"

Tags: objective-c

"The sigma notation is shorthand for a summation. Its use here means to add the values
of 1/2^i, where i varies from 1 to n. That is, add 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 .... If you make the
value of n large enough, the sum of this series should approach 1. Let’s experiment with
different values for n to see how close we get."

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// Define the Fraction class
@interface Fraction : NSObject
{
int numerator;
int denominator;
}
@property int numerator, denominator;
-(void) print;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(Fraction*) add: (Fraction *) f;
-(void) reduce;
@end    

#import "Fraction.h"
@implementation Fraction
@synthesize numerator, denominator;
-(void) print
{
NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d
{
numerator = n;
denominator = d;
}
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{
// To add two fractions:
// a/b + c/d = ((a*d) + (b*c)) / (b * d)
// result will store the result of the addition
Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator +
denominator * f.numerator;
result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
[result reduce];
return result; 
}

#import "Fraction.h"
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *sum = [[Fraction alloc] init], *sum2;
int i, n, pow2;
[sum setTo: 0 over: 1]; // set 1st fraction to 0
NSLog (@"Enter your value for n:");
scanf ("%i", &n);
pow2 = 2;

for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
[aFraction setTo: 1 over: pow2];
sum2 = [sum add: aFraction];
[sum release]; // release previous sum
sum = sum2;
pow2 *= 2;
}

NSLog (@"After %i iterations, the sum is %g", n, [sum convertToNum]);
[aFraction release];
[sum release];
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Question: Why do we have to create additional variable sum2 that we are using in the "for" loop? Why do we need  "release previous sum" here and then again give it a value that we just released? :

```
sum2 = [sum add: aFraction];
[sum release]; // release previous sum
sum = sum2;
```

Is it just for the sake of avoiding memory leakage? (method "add" initializes a variable that is stored in sum2)

Comment: fyi: homework tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing how `Fraction` is defined, I can't be sure, but I'd guess that a `Fraction` object is *immutable* so that `sum` can't simply be changed.  If we did `sum = [sum add:aFraction]`, it would leak the object that `sum` used to point to (it had a positive retain count, still does, and we no longer have a pointer to it).

Comment: You were too fast Isaac! I was adding the interface and the implementation files in the main post. Please, check it.

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov: Okay, at a quick glance, I'll stick to my original answer, more or less: `add:` returns a new `Fraction` that is the sum rather than modifying the `Fraction` it's called on.  I'll also note that the `add:` method as defined violates naming conventions because it returns a `Fraction` object with a retain count of +1 but the method name doesn't have `copy` (or whatever the other keywords are).  Without the implementation, I'd have expected `add:` to return an autoreleased object, which would have had to be retained in `main`.

Comment: So i should memorize that if we use method that creates new instances then we have to create additional variable in our "main" program to store that object that was initiated in method. Is that correct? Also  your last note about "violation of naming conventions" isn't clear for me. What should i google to find out about that?

Comment: It's more about understanding what the retain count is on each object than memorizing rules for various situations.  Take a look at [Apple's Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and the various other guides to which it links.

Comment: To expand on Isaac's comment, all you should need to learn is that methods with 'new', 'alloc', 'retain' or 'copy' in their name return something you own and that you're responsible for throwing away. All other methods return things you don't own so they'll automatically go away (unless you do something specific in order to keep them). If you run the analyser built into Xcode then it'll confirm you've followed the rules appropriately and the theory behind ARC is that the compiler can go beyond that by applying most of the rules for you (though the code as given definitely isn't ARC code).

Comment: What Tommy says is correct in terms of the naming conventions (and using the analyzer is always a *very* good idea), but I meant "understanding what the retain count is on each object" as a much broader suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the `Fraction` class that is most likely part of the book, it's likely just an example of immutable object usage.

Immutable objects are generally advocated because:

- it's easy to make them thread safe; and
- because they're guaranteed not to change everyone can reliably hold onto the same one rather than copying the value ad nauseam.

So you can multiprocess to your heart's content and in any reasonably complex system you usually save memory while remaining object oriented (ie, each object is sovereign and nobody else directly manipulates an object's internal data).

Being immutable, you have to create a new one when you want to 'modify' an existing one, which I think is what's going on here.

EDIT: with the full source for `Fraction` being given it looks like the object is actually mutable (eg, it has `setTo:over:`). So the answer is still that the old object is thrown away and the new one kept because the `add:` doesn't mutate the object it's called on but rather returns a new object with the net result. Stylistically though it seems more like a pursuit of [three address form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code) than the immutable object pattern.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I added the interface and the implementation files in the main post.